# MySQL SELECT a single row having a certain column value after performing other column checks

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a table containing metadata of photos: which gallery photo belongs to, which person it belongs to (person could be identified either by name, or by internal id assigned inside each gallery), whether or not a person in a photo wears regular glasses or dark glasses, or neither:

```
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| id | gallery_id | person_id_in_gallery |  person_name_id  |  wear_glasses  |  wear_sunglasses | image_filename |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  1 |     1      |          1           |       NULL       |       1        |         0        |       xa.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  2 |     1      |          1           |       NULL       |       1        |         0        |       xb.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  3 |     1      |          3           |       NULL       |       1        |         0        |       xc.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  4 |     2      |          1           |       NULL       |       0        |         1        |       ya.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  5 |     2      |          2           |       NULL       |       0        |         1        |       yb.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  6 |     2      |          2           |       NULL       |       0        |         1        |       yc.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  7 |     2      |          3           |       NULL       |       0        |         1        |       yd.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  8 |     3      |         NULL         |         1        |       1        |         0        |       za.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  9 |     3      |         NULL         |         1        |       1        |         0        |       zb.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| 10 |     3      |         NULL         |         2        |       0        |         1        |       zc.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| 11 |     3      |         NULL         |         2        |       0        |         1        |       zd.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| 12 |     3      |         NULL         |         3        |       0        |         0        |       ze.jpg   |
+----+------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Now, my task is to obtain a list of photos that contain a person wearing either reg. glasses or dark glasses, but I need to only find one such photo of EACH of the people in the whole table. It gets slightly complicated, because a person could be identified either by global id throughout all databases (person_name_id), or by a local id in each gallery (person_id_in_gallery). The desired query result is as follows:

```
+----------------+
| image_filename |
+----------------+
|       xa.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       xc.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       ya.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       yb.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       yd.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       za.jpg   |
+----------------+
|       zc.jpg   |
+----------------+
```

Here is a query I used to obtain all the photos with glasses and sunglasses.

```
SELECT image_filename FROM photos_table WHERE (wear_glasses = 1 or wear_sunglasses = 1) and (person_id_in_gallery IS NOT NULL or person_name_id IS NOT NULL)
```

However, all my attempts to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY statements to pick a single photo from each unique person failed, and I would greatly appreciate help with using them properly in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following (tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47711126fbdae7cae25ebc6651f94255))

```
SELECT MIN(image_filename) AS image_filename
FROM photos_table
WHERE (wear_glasses = 1 or wear_sunglasses = 1) 
AND (person_id_in_gallery IS NOT NULL or person_name_id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY gallery_id, person_id_in_gallery, person_name_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution definitely works, and the use of MIN function like this is something I just learned from you.